# ManyToMany relationship,need pass ONLY id in PASS JSON method. Git include

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-one

I have a three entities: Article, Author, and Category.
Author can have a lot of Article.
Category can have a lot of Article.
Article can have one Author and one Category.

I want to make the POST method like that:
{
"title" : "Title13",
"categoryOfArticle": 2,
"authorOfArticle" : 6
}

But when I start i get:

```
WARN 11752 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver :
```

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
JSON parse error:
Cannot construct instance of `com.dataart.newsportal.entities.Category`
(although at least one Creator exists):
no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2);
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
Cannot construct instance of `com.dataart.newsportal.entities. Category` (although at least one Creator exists):
no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (2) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream);
line: 4, column: 22] (through reference chain: com.dataart.newsportal.entities.Article["categoryOfArticle"])]

What should I do to pass id values successfully?

```
Main Entity:    
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLES", schema = "NEWS_SCHEMA")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Article {

 @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    private byte[] content;



    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    //@JsonManagedReference
    private Category categoryOfArticle;


    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Author.class,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    //@JsonManagedReference
    private Author authorOfArticle;


    public Article(String title, Category categoryOfArticle, Author authorOfArticle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.categoryOfArticle = categoryOfArticle;
        this.authorOfArticle = authorOfArticle;
    }



@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORS", schema = "NEWS_SCHEMA")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH")
    private Date dob;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},
            mappedBy = "authorOfArticle")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Article> articlesOfAuthor;

    public void addArticleToAuthor(Article article) {

        if (articlesOfAuthor == null) {
            articlesOfAuthor = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        articlesOfAuthor.add(article);

        article.setAuthorOfArticle(this);
    }

    public Author(String name, String surname, Date dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dob = dob;
    }


}

public class Category {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;



@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},
        mappedBy = "categoryOfArticle")
@JsonBackReference
private List<Article> articlesInCategory;

public void addArticleInCategoriesList(Article article){

    if (articlesInCategory == null){
        articlesInCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    articlesInCategory.add(article);
    article.setCategoryOfArticle(this);
}

public Category(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Service:

```
@Service
public class ArticleServiceImpl implements ArticleService {

    @Autowired
    AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ArticleRepository articleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Override
    public Article getArticle(int id) {

        Article article = null;
        Optional<Article> optional = articleRepository.findById(id);

        if (optional.isPresent()){
            article = optional.get();
        }

        return article;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> getAllArticles() {
        return articleRepository.findAll();
    }


   

    @Override
    public void saveArticle(Article article) {



        article.getCategoryOfArticle().addArticleInCategoriesList(article);

        article.getAuthorOfArticle().addArticleToAuthor(article);

        articleRepository.save(article);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteArticle(int id) {
        articleRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

I tried to add new fields authorId and categoryId in Articke class.And new constructor:

```
public Article(String title, int categoryIdent, int authorIdent) {
this.title = title;
this.categoryIdent = categoryIdent;
this.authorIdent = authorIdent;
  }
```

Then add this:

```
int authorId = article.getAuthorIdent();
article.setAuthorOfArticle(authorRepository.getById(authorId));
int categoryId = article.getCategoryIdent();
article.setCategoryOfArticle(categoryRepository.getById(categoryId));
```

To addArticle() method in ArticleServiceImpl for getting Article instance of id. But that's doesn't work

[Git:](https://github.com/Vsevolod-Tsukanov/news_portal/tree/problem_branch)

Comment: Either use `targetEntity` or `mappedBy` both used for mapped table

Comment: If you want `setForeinKey()` manually then put `insertable = false,updatable = false` otherwise not

Comment: Where shoud i set insertable = false,updatable = false ?

Comment: If you want to insert foreign key column manually